# I'm having window.open() problems?

Tags: javascript

Alright, so I have this function that makes an account for me using window.open but the problem is that it logs **"Window opened"** but after that it doesn't log anything, no errors, and it doesn't make the account. Could anyone think of a reason why it is doing this?

```
var accountPassword = "testPassword512"

function checkUsername(username, callback) {
    $.get("http://www.roblox.com/UserCheck/DoesUsernameExist?username=" + username, function(data) {
        callback(data.success); // true = taken , false = not taken
    });
};



function makeNewAccount(accountName) {
    checkUsername(accountName, function(response) {
        if (response == false) {
            console.log("Making account: " + accountName)
            signupWindow = window.open("http://www.roblox.com/login/signup.aspx");
            console.log("Window opened");
            signupWindow.document.getElementById('SignupUsername').val(accountName);
            signupWindow.document.getElementById('SignupPassword').val(accountPassword);
            signupWindow.document.getElementById('SignupPasswordConfirm').val(accountPassword);
            signupWindow.document.getElementById("birthdayMonthSelect").value = 0;
            signupWindow.document.getElementById("birthdayDaySelect").value = 0;
            signupWindow.document.getElementById("birthdayYearSelect").value = 25;
            console.log("done with values");
            signupWindow.document.getElementByClassName('.gender-circle').click();
            console.log("done choosing gender");
            signupWindow.document.getElementById('SignUpButton').submit();
            console.log("account made");
        } else {
            return true; // true = account taken , false = not taken
        }

    });

}
makeNewAccount('240213mfasd')
```

Comment: I don't know if it is the problem, but you certainly forgot a coma at the end of your password variable declaration (line 1). And at the very last line too, when you call the function.

Comment: Is that popup window from a different domain, or is it your own (the same one that your script runs on)? If it’s the former, then the Same Origin Policy prevents you from doing what you are trying to do.

Comment: @CBroe I'm running it on the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing "jQuery" (`.val()`) with "not jQuery" (`.value =`)

Don't do that.

Comment: Fixed it, and it still doesn't log the stuff after it.

Comment: It’s hard to believe that this would not have caused errors in console …

Comment: Is it supposed to actually open a window, because it isn't doing that.